# Program crashes when trying to start it outside Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So, i've got a little problem with my Code::Blocks IDE. i know this question shouldnt belong here, but ive asked this question a while ago on different forums, and so far, no one was able to help me - so im trying it here now.
I configured my CB so it would compile with MinGW64 on Windows 8.1, made a little trivial console program which prints something, and compiled with -m64 .So far, so good. When i build it and then start it with CB, it runs just fine, but when im trying to launch the executable found in the bin folder, the program crashes at startup, telling me that it couldnt start correctly (Error Code: 0xc000007b) . So, can anybody help me here? i would greatly appreciate it. Again, running it using CB works just fine, just double-clicking the exe ends with the error said before.

Comment: Are you checking that your app is loading 64-bit versions of the DLL's it is dependent on? Windows does not check the bitness of DLL's or EXE's when starting apps. So if a DLL happens to have the same name for both 64 and 32 bit versions, Windows loads the first one it finds, and if the bitness doesn't match your EXE, well you have problems as you're seeing now.

Comment: using the TDM-GCC x64 compiler instead of this one works great.